# Validating match of two password fields Redux-Form

Tags: redux-form

I have a registration form which consists of:

- Username
- Password
- Password verification

The user has to input the same password in both fields, or else an error message should appear underneath Password verification: "Passwords don't match"

I'm using Redux-Form and get wrap my head around how to create this verification.

I'm trying to use field level verification for that: [field level verification](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/)

I also get the password value from redux:

```
const selector = formValueSelector('register');
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    password: selector(state, 'Password')
  };
};
```

So, I wrote the following validation function:

```
  const matchPasswords = pass1 =>pass2 => 
  pass1  !== pass2 ? 'Passwords don't match' : undefined;
```

And I pass it to the verification field like so:

```
 <Field
   name="username"
   type="text"
   component={renderField}
   label="Username"
   validate={[matchPasswords(this.props.password]}
 />
```

But it doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You said it "doesn't work" - can you elaborate?

Answer (score 22):

Found a solution:

Use allValues:

```js
const passwordsMatch = (value, allValues) => 
  value !== allValues.password ? 'Passwords don\'t match' : undefined;
```

Answer (score 10):

To add to @DM's answer, `value` and `allValues` **args do not need to be passed in to this validation function** from the parent component. Here is a complete example:

*`<Field />` Component:*

```
...
<Field
  type="password"
  name="passwordConfirmation"
  validate={[required, passwordsMustMatch]} 
/>
```

*`passwordsMustMatch` validation:*

```
export const passwordsMustMatch = (value, allValues) => 
  value !== allValues.password ? 
    'Passwords do not match' :
     undefined
```